# Size function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am a new in MATLAB and I have a problem understanding the function `size`
in this statement: `for i=1:size(scale,2)` WHERE scale can be any integer number .e.g scale=5.

I found that in MATLAB help `size(A,1)` returns the number of rows of A , and 
`size(A,2)` returns the number of columns of A.

Now I'm really confused as to what is the functionality of (size).

Answer (score 12):

As you know, matlab deals mainly with matrices. So, the size function gives you the dimension of a matrix depending on how you use it. For example:
1. If you say `size(A)`, it will give you a vector of size 2 of which the first entry is the number of rows in A and the second entry is the number of columns in A.
2. If you call `size(A, 1)`, size will return a scalar equal to the number of rows in A.
3. If you call `size(A, 2)`, size will return a scalar equal to the number of columns in A.

A scalar like `scale` in your example is considered as a vector of size 1 by 1. So, size(scale, 2) will return 1, I believe.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Did you mean that the statment for i=1:size(scale,2) will itrate just one time , WHERE.e.g scale=5 ?

Comment: This is true only when `A` is a 2D matrix. More generally, `size` returns a vector whose _length_ is equal to `ndims(A)`.

Comment: sorry for more qs:) I didn't get the idea well. Other statment such as size(image,3) what did number 3 means here? , I'm forget to say that I'm dealing with images.

Comment: @JasmineAl-Qahtani Please read the help docs. These are very basic questions that are answered by the first few lines in the help documentation.

Comment: Actually read the help, rather than just copying it and pasting it here and asking us to explain it for you. Try the tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

The Linear Algebra operations in Matlab/octave by default follow Row-Column order (ie they are row major by default); so if A is a matrix of size 3x2 (3 rows and 2 columns), we can use size to determine the order of matrix/vector 
`size(A)` will return 3 2 (the first entry representing no.of rows & the second one is no.of columns). Similarly, 
`size(A,1)` returns 3 (1 here represents the no. of rows and A has 3 rows)
`size(A,2)` returns 2 (2 here represents the no. of columns and A has 2 columns)